# while loop, if statement error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason when using this code  it gives me a white screen, and I can't find the problem in it?

```
while ($monsterhp > 0 && $yourhp > 0) {

if ($pokemon4['speed'] => $row['speed']) {

$monsterhp = floor($monsterhp - $mydmg);

if($yourhp > 0) {
$yourhp = floor($yourhp - $monsterdmg);
}

}elseif ($pokemon4['speed'] < $row['speed']) {

$yourhp = floor($yourhp - $monsterdmg);

if ($monsterhp > 0) {
$monsterhp = floor($monsterhp - $mydmg);
}

}
}
```

Comment: whats the error message, if you enable error reporting and output?

Comment: Doesn't display any error, with error reporting enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you had an error in this operator: `=>` (greater than or equal)

It should be like this: `>=`

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, thank you lol I will accept the answer after the 10mins.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in second line of code... 
`=>` will try to assign value to the array key, where `>=` means "greater or equal than".

Also, when you have white screen that's usually parser error, to see your errors you can check your php error log. The path depends on your system and server settings and it's defined in `php.ini` file. Usually though simple `error_reporting(E_ALL)` inside your php file works fine and throws errors on the screen. It's strongly advised during development to have them `ON` so you can develop bug-free code. On the other hand, when on production server, turn them `OFF` to avoid exposing your code errors (if any) to the public.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```